# Redirect to href if javascript return true

Tags: javascript, php

I have a `<a>` link and a checkbox, I want to redirect to the href only if the javascript returns true (the box is checked)

Here is my code :

My javascript file :

```
function fb_checkbox() {
    if (document.getElementById("checkAGB").checked == false) {
        document.getElementById('notAccepted').style.display = "block";
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
```

In my PHP file :

```
<a href="'.$loginUrl.'" onclick="fb_checkbox();">Sign in with Facebook</a>
```

Comment: use here onclick="return javascript:fb_checkbox();" instead

Comment: Doesn't work, the javascript is executed but the redirection works even if I don't check the checkbox

Comment: onclick="return fb_checkbox();" this would help you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this in the javascript:

`function fb_checkbox(url) {
...
    else{
      window.location.href = url;
    }`

And in the PHP side:

```
<a href="'.$loginUrl.'" onclick="fb_checkbox(this.href);return false;">Sign in with Facebook</a>
```

And it should work.

Comment: This executes the Javascript but even without checking the box, the href is redirected

Comment: I missed: `return false;` after onclick function call. The full, functional code:

`<input type="checkbox" id="checkAGB"> <a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="fb_checkbox(this.href);return false;">Sign in with Facebook</a>

<div style="display:none" id="notAccepted">Check the checkbox!</div>


<script>
 function fb_checkbox(url) {
     if (document.getElementById("checkAGB").checked == false) {
         document.getElementById('notAccepted').style.display = "block";
         return false;
     }else{
         window.location.href = url;
     }
 }
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `return` in `onclick` attribute's value.

Try this:

```
<a href="'.$loginUrl.'" onclick="return fb_checkbox();">Sign in with Facebook</a>
```

Here's working example:

```js
function fb_checkbox() {
    if (document.getElementById("checkAGB").checked == false) {
        document.getElementById('notAccepted').style.display = "block";
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAGB"/>
<div id="notAccepted" style="display:none">Check the checkbox!</div>
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="return fb_checkbox();">Works</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="fb_checkbox();">Sign in with Facebook</a>

function fb_checkbox() {
    if (document.getElementById("checkAGB").checked == false) {
        document.getElementById('notAccepted').style.display = "block";
        return false;
    }else{
        window.location.href="<?=$loginUrl?>";
    }
```